# Is user on a tablet?

Tags: .net, tablet-pc

Is there any way to accurately determine if an application is running on a tablet computer?

Comment: What is a tablet computer to you? Can it have a keyboard? Does it need to have a touch screen? Do you require a minimum screen size? Does it run a special tablet os or can it run a regular desktop os?

Answer (score 4):

You could probably check the [Windows Version](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304283), I'm sure the Tablet PC edition has a specific version

Comment: this is how i have done this with our tablets but it of course will depend on what OS your tablets have.

Comment: As you might have noticed, that page is really old. I guess the Tablet PC OS version should have a different element in it's version, but I do not know which that is.

Comment: Does anyone care to explain me which versions of Windows are for tablets?

Comment: XP Tablet Edition, any Vista, any Win7.